Cosmographia not starting in Ubuntu
I recently got Ubuntu in my laptop. I installed the cosmographia version 4.2 for Linux. After installation the cosmographia runs when run using the installer GUI. However after shutting down this window, the program stops opening up using the command
./Cosmographia

and starts throwing up errors. One error that I have encountered most often,
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'


Current thread 0x0000721db268b440 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to the lib folder inside cosmographia. In the lib folder you can find python3.5 and encodings module in it. Still the program throws this error. I have tried using a virutal environment with conda, but that just seems to give another set of errors listed below,
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 559, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 540, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 281, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 257, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 247, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 607, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 556, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/home/nikita/miniconda3/envs/cosmo/lib/python3.5/sysconfig.py", line 427, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu'

./Cosmographia

I was expecting cosmographia to work and open up the GUI. What can I try next?

Are you really on Python 3.5!? This version is out of suppprt since several years back. Probably fix that before you try anything else.

This really needs a [mcve], i.e. precise steps you took for installation. Before you do that, consider reading up on Python's venv module though, because that allows you to create isolated environments to install different things without stepping on each other.

To anyone who is facing the same problem. I wasn't able to solve the issue of running cosmographia using ./Cosmograhia. But cosmographia can be run using a shell file present in the same directory, with the following command:
./Cosmographia.sh
Hope this helps.
